# Report Viewer in MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reporting-services

I have looked around and tinkered dozens of times but I cant get my report view page to work on my MVC project... Here's what I did so far:

- Created a ASP.NET project
- Create a specific webform for the reportviewer control
- Add & Setup the Report Viewer Control
- Run

The thing here is that the reportviewer does appear, render the parameters for the report I pointed it to and everything. But when I click "View Report", a loading appears, then theres a refresh, and we are back to square zero...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior was caused by a PostBack not being checked... silly me... bad developer!